# trying to code a survey i don't know how to get the subtraction to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, subtraction, survey

I'm trying to code a survey-type thing. one of the things I'm trying to make it do is calculate your age.
can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
birth = int(input('what year were you born in?'))
year = int(input('what year is it?'))
print(int(year-birth) + ' that is your age')
```

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong?

Comment: You received an error message: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`. You should have posted this error message with your question. Apart from this - it tells you what the problem is - you cannot add a string and an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add an `int` to a `str` so either convert to a string before concatenation

```
print(str(year-birth) + ' that is your age')
```

or use `str.format`

```
print('{} that is your age'.format(year-birth))
```

or use and f-string

```
print(f'{year-birth} that is your age')
```

Comment: Or, use f-string!
```print(f"{year-birth} that is your age")```

Comment: `f-strings` are also a nice way to print. Usable since python3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the code below

```
birth = int(input('what year were you born in?'))
year = int(input('what year is it?'))
print((year-birth) , 'that is your age')
```

as you have stated int as your birth and year the program will understand that u are adding 2 int together instead of string. Another thing is that you arent able to add a int and a string together, hence you will need to use comma.

Hope this helps! :D